# Real projective plane: $f_*$ isomorphism $\implies f$ surjective

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

Suppose we have a continuous map $f: \mathbb{R}P^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}P^2$ that induces an isomorphism in homology $f_*: H_p(\mathbb{R}P^2) \rightarrow H_p(\mathbb{R}P^2)\ \ \ \forall p$. 
How do I show that $f$ is surjective?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If it is not surjective, than it is actually a map to punctured projective plane.
Punctured projective plane is homotopy equivalent to $\mathbb{R}P^1 = S^1$. 
Now look at the induced map $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}=H_1(\mathbb{R}P^1) \to H_1(S^1)=\mathbb{Z}$. It must be zero. But that contradicts the fact that the original homology map is an isomorphism (something must go to the cycle in $S^1$)