# Isomorphism in homology of $\mathbb{R} P^2$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, projective-space

I have a question about the homology of the real projective space $\mathbb{R} P^2$ with which I'm having some trouble:

**Let $f: \mathbb{R}P^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}P^2$ be a map which induces an isomorphism in homology. Why is $f$ surjective?**

I know that the homology of $\mathbb{R}P^2$ is as follows:

$H_0(\mathbb{R}P^2) = \mathbb{Z}$,

$H_1(\mathbb{R}P^2) = \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$

$H_i(\mathbb{R}P^2) = 0$ for any $i \neq 0,1$.

This is true for any homology theory (by the use of cellular homology).

What I've tried is to lift $f$ to a map $g: S^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}P^2$ and then arrive at a contradiction to $f$ being an isomorphism in homology when assuming that the degree of $g$ is zero. From this it would follow that $deg(g) \neq 0$, hence $g$ is surjective (and therefore also $f$). However this argument doesn't work because $H_2(\mathbb{R}P^2) = 0$.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT:** Even though my initial search was fruitless I just now found a more or less satisfying answer: [Real projective plane: $f_*$ isomorphism $\implies f$ surjective](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/631683/real-projective-plane-f-isomorphism-implies-f-surjective?rq=1)

Comment: If $f$ is not surjective, then $f:\mathbb RP^2\rightarrow\mathbb RP^2-\{pt\}$. And compute $H(f):H(\mathbb RP^2)\rightarrow H(\mathbb RP^2-\{pt\})$. This is my thought, but does it work?

Comment: @TomBombadil: More or less? Which part do you not understand?

Comment: @TooOldForMath: I do understand the answer, but it is a bit too condensed for my taste. It took me quite a while to understand it after I read it. Plus, there is a typo which initially also caused some confusion for me: it should be $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} = H_1(\mathbb{R}P^2)$ instead of $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} = H_1(\mathbb{R}P^1)$.

Answer (score 3):

$\Bbb RP^2$ is a Moebius strip with a disk attached along its boundary. You can convince yourself of this by considering $\Bbb RP^2$ as the quotient space of a hemisphere
$$S^2_+=S^2\cap\lbrace z\geq 0\rbrace$$
(with $S^2=\lbrace(x,y,z)\in\Bbb R^3\mid x^2+y^2+z^2=1\rbrace$) under the equivalence relation identifying a point of the equator (i.e. with $z=0$) to its opposite. In any case, $\Bbb RP^2\setminus\lbrace\mathrm{pt}\rbrace$ is homeomorphic to a Moebius strip, and thus homotopy equivalent to a circle. Since homology groups are homotopy invariants, and $H_1(\Bbb RP^2\setminus\lbrace\mathrm{pt}\rbrace)\simeq H_1(S^1)$ is free abelian on one generator, it isn't isomorphic to $H_1(\Bbb RP^2)$.