# Surjective map on real projective space

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

If $f$ is map of $\mathbf{RP}^2$, inducing an isomorphism in homology, then $f$ is surjective. How can one prove this, maybe using some kind of CW complex structure on it or how?

Comment: By a map of $\Bbb R \mathrm P^2$, do you mean $\Bbb R \mathrm P^2 \to \Bbb R \mathrm P^2$?

Comment: Exact duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/655791/isomorphism-in-homology-of-mathbbr-p2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose $f$ misses a point $p \in \Bbb R \mathrm{P}^2$. Then $f$ factors through $Y = \Bbb R \mathrm{P}^2 - \{p\}$:
$$
\Bbb R \mathrm{P}^2 \xrightarrow{g} Y \xrightarrow{i} \Bbb R \mathrm{P}^2
$$

$Y$ is homotopy equivalent to $S^1$. Consider the fundamental polygon of $\Bbb R \mathrm{P}^2$ to see this. This forces $g_* : H_1(\Bbb R \mathrm{P}^2) \to H_1(Y)$ to be trivial since $H_1(\Bbb R \mathrm{P}^2) \cong \Bbb Z_2$ and $H_1(Y) \cong \Bbb Z$.

It follows that $f_* = i_* \circ g_*$ cannot be an isomorphism.

Comment: Did you considered the case $f$ missing more than $1$ point? It seems the proof is not complete.

Comment: @user32240 It doesn't matter whether $f$ misses more points or not as long as it misses at least one. The proof doesn't assume that $g$ is surjective.

Comment: @user32240: if you really think that the proof is not complete you should refresh your logic

Comment: @amoreacceptablename: I think the proof would be complete if Ayman mentioned $g$ is continuous.

Comment: Well this is obvious.